# How to calculate who is accepted order first?

Tags: c#, mysql, algorithm, rabbitmq

There are some users. They can perform orders. Orders could be send for all users.

When user gets order he can accept or decline this during 1 minute.

If user accept order I store information in MySQL.

```
id | order_id | user_id | timestamp
1    1          1         12345679
2    1          2         59589333
```

When one minute left, nobody can accept order.

After that my service handles all stored data and calculates who was accepted order first.

Problem is that user can accept order faster that another, but due internet connection or others reasons date will be distorted.

There are two ways:

One (calculate time on client side in moment acception):

1. User accepts order
2. Get current timestamp
3. Send current timestamp to server
4. Store current timestamp in Db

Second (calculate time on server in moment storing data in Db)

1. User accepts order
2. Send data to server
3. Get current timestamp
4. Store current timestamp in Db

So, it is no guarantee of sorting users by created timestamp. And I can not assign order first user, cause I am not confident in time.

Comment: It sounds like you need a high degree of real-time precision.  What precision is that?  Every system will have uncertainty.  What level of temporal uncertainty can you tolerate?  It sounds like it's very important to you to know which person actually clicked their mouse first in real time.  Most first-come-first-served web strategies don't go to any particular pains to correct network latency, etc, in cases like this.  Is there any particular reason that it's so important for you?

Comment: Main reason is to solve  
uncertainty if two users accepts one order at the same time.

Comment: Also should I use queue to store all accepted orders?

Comment: But how important is that uncertainty?  If person 1 clicks "accept", then person 2 clicks "accept" 30ms later in the real world, but due to latency, processing, etc, person 2's entry is logged first at the server.  Is that *really* a problem for you?  Is it actually critical that person 1 is awarded the order because their mouse clicked first in the real world?  Or are you getting just getting mired in minutiae and making your job ten times harder for yourself for nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow internet connection or others reasons are the users problem. You should only care about witch orders reached your server faster. You can use this to send orders to your database.

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_id , user_id, reached_time) VALUES(1, 1, NOW());
```

Then select them like this.

```
SELECT id, order_id, user_id FROM orders WHERE reached_time < '2020-01-01 01-00-00' ORDER BY reached_time ASC;
```

Datetime '2020-01-01 01-00-00' is the deadline and any order after this will not be selected.